# jScrollPane v2.0.0 (beta11) strange behaviour in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I'm using jQuery and jScrollPane to create scrollable section on my website with custom scrollbar. I walked into some issue, that i can not resolve by myself.

I've setup some test page to demonstrate the case: http://bs-dev.ru/jscrollpane-test/

As you can see i have a UL-list with LI-items in it. Every item consists of the text-box with title and container for two other boxes. Container's position is set to relative and two boxes are stacked one over another with position absolute and specific coordinates. In real-life scenario the big box is a picture and the small box is a button linked to specific action with this picture.

In Google Chrome when you scroll the pane to the bottom with mousewheel - the container shifts up and gets over the title-box which is not desired in any way.

Looks like we having a bug with jScrollPane here, so i wanted it's authors to be noticed, so they can fix it and make this great plugin even more awesome = )

And my question is - how can i preserve the look and functionality of this layout getting rid of this issue at the same time? Maybe you can suggest a way to alter my layout so it's no longer based on position - absolute/relative.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reduced test case clearly showing the problem :)

And what a strange problem it is! I'm not sure what is going on in the browsers rendering engine to cause it but I think I have a solution. I added `position: relative` to the CSS rule for `.Title` (around line 72) in the Chrome developer tools and that seemed to fix things.

Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Thank you Kelvin, it works! I don't know how i couldn't come to this solution by myself. I just made entire LI element relatively positioned - so simple.

I suggest to find the source of the problem or at least add this example to the documentation, so others can benefit from our discovery as well )